# How to use customized built-in element in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, built-in, custom-element

I made a custom element extends built-in element like `<button is="my-button">`. But it's not working when I use it in VueJs. Because maybe VueJs use `is` attribute for its components.

Is there any good solution for this?

- `<button is="my-button">` -> `<my-button>`:
  Vue try to make its component. and then my button is broken.
- `<button is="my-button" v-pre>`:
  It works for `button` element but data binding in button is not working.
- `<button v-my-custom-directive="'my-button'">`:
  It works and it's my latest solution... But it seems ugly. I should use quotation marks for avoid `undefined variable error`. I don't want to suggest other people who use my element in VueJs.

Sample code: https://jsbin.com/yucojat/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Do you mean that `my-button` is your custom built-in component?

Comment: Yes https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-customized-builtin-example

Comment: @hyeong-min, did you find any solution i'm too looking for a solution